# Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData v8.0.2 Case Insensitive fields name

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, odata

I implemented OData V8 with Asp Core 5.0 I need to make the fields' name case insensitive in the query, for example:

- url/$filter=MyField eq 1   <- should work
- url/$filter=myfield eq 1   <- also should work

I did the following implementation:

```
services.AddControllers()
                    .AddOData(opt => {
                        opt.AddRouteComponents("", model0, sv => {
                            sv.AddSingleton<ODataUriResolver>(f => {
                                return new ODataUriResolver {
                                    EnableCaseInsensitive = true,
                                };
                            });
                        });
                })
```

My solution didn't work, OData request does not recognize the field if it didn't match the case of the Object Model.

How can I enable the CaseInsensitive with OData V8?

Many Thanks

Comment: So far, there's no setting to config case insensitive for the query option. Until we have that, you might use "middleware" to re-word the query option? or add duplicate properties using a different cases? or if it's ok, you can enable lower camel case when building the Edm model.

Comment: @Sameh did you manage to find a workaround in the meantime?

Comment: @crollywood Yes, I downgraded the OData nuget, but can't remember the version